# Automatic backup of emacs file edit on a server

Tags: emacs, backup, cluster-computing

I have a large repository of C++ code on a remote cluster (linux OS). When I need to work on this code from my home computer (Ubuntu OS), I try to access these codes through emacs on X windows. However the X window connection is very slow making the editing a painful process. So I sometimes move files manually between my local drive and remote cluster to edit the files. My question is: is there a way to configure my local emacs, such that when I edit the file in my local space, it would automatically be backed up in the cluster where it can then be compiled?

**UPDATE:1**

I installed TRAMP and it works well for servers that can be connected directly. However I also have servers which can be connected only when I activate VPN. How to provide the VPN information to TRAMP to connect to this server?

The other question I had was how to stop the TRAMP when it waits for prompts from remote shell without having to kill the whole emacs buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about VPN connections: why would a client like TRAMP need to know that packets are routed through a VPN? I would tend to think that once the VPN is correctly configured, all outgoing connections to the relevant hosts would automatically be routed to the correct interface, without the client having to specify anything... Or might you explain the commands you have to run in a command-line to ssh to the VPN-only server?

Comment: As for your second question, I edited my answer.

Comment: You say you "installed" Tramp ... Doesn't it come included with Emacs since something like v22 at least?

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure if it was included with Emacs. I installed it myself.

Comment: @Francesco I need to connect to a server. The connection to server can be initiated by starting a cisco-vpn. I can connect to this server through ssh in linux terminal. However the TRAMP just hangs and it never gets connected. I used exactly the same steps that you have specified in your answer. I'm able to connect to servers that just need passwd but not to those that needs a VPN connection and RSA token along with a passwd.

Comment: Are there any environment variables involved in this VPN's setup and usage? Since TRAMP internally uses `ssh`, there's no reason that you could connect to your server using `ssh` in a terminal but Emacs TRAMP couldn't do the same.

Comment: @Francesco I dont think of any special environment variables used in VPN usage. The access to server involves two level authentication, where I first need to provide an RSA token and then a passwd. I'm not sure if TRAMP can handle this kind of a two level authentication. I tried to google but I could not get any answer on this issue.

Comment: I'm no expert of VPNs, so I fear I can not be of much help for you on this issue. You could maybe ask another SO question specifically on this issue.

Comment: If you can connect to the server using ssh, maybe you would be able to establish an SSH tunnel that TRAMP could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically a use case where [TRAMP](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) would be useful.

Instead of connecting to the server using SSH and opening Emacs there with X forwarding, run Emacs on your box and open your files remotely using TRAMP. For example:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>`/ssh:user@host:/remote/path/to/the/file`<kbd>RET</kbd>

This way, your Emacs process runs locally, but all file operations (e.g. save, revert, ...) are forwarded to the server, and all shell commands issued from TRAMP buffers also run on the remote server (this includes `M-x compile`)

---

**UPDATE:1**

When TRAMP hangs waiting for a remote shell prompt (which tends to happen frequently for reasons which are still obscure to me), I usually kill the underlying `ssh` process (`htop` with tree-like view is a good tool to do this) . TRAMP notices this and automatically respawns the killed process to resume operations.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this tonight or tomorrow. If it serves my purpose I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to run Emacs in a console on the remote server?  All Emacs functions can be access via the keyboard and once you get used to the key combinations it usually works out faster.

That way you will be running faster than forwarding an X session - running in a console is what Emacs was designed for.

As an added bonus - if you get used to using Gnu screen - http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/  you can pick up your sessions exactly as they were if the connection drops.  In fact with screen you can shutdown your laptop at the end of the day - login over SSH the next day and pick up all your 'screens' exactly as they were the day before.  This will include any open editors, debug sessions etc.

Gnu screen is available as a package on Debian and probably most Linux distributions.